# Combining rows by ID

Tags: r

I have a large dataset and I would like to combine rows that have the same ID into one row, without losing any information.

To start with, here is my long data:

```
 # A random data frame
    df1  <- read.table(text="question ID  ARG  AUT ITA
                              A     90   NA  all   never
                              A     90   NA  all   NA
                              A1    91   12  NA    NA
                              A2    92   14  two   41
                              A3    93   17  NA    44
                              AA    90   20  NA    NA
                              B2    91   NA  NA    NA
                              B3    92   NA  four  NA
                              B4    93   NA  10    yes", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
# A random data frame
    df1  <- read.table(text="question ID  ARG  AUT ITA
                              A     90   20  all   never
                              A1    91   12  13    61
                              A2    92   14  two   41
                              A3    93   17  10    yes ", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Please note that my actual dataset is in the wide format and includes more variables / columns than in the example above.

I was thinking about the `aggregate()` function, but I don't know how to implement it, because I have character values to be "aggregated". I would be very grateful for any suggestion how to tackle this issue!

Answer (score 2):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise_all(list(~ .[!is.na(.)][1]))
```

Comment: I just tried this on my dataset and it removes all my duplicates, but I am losing information, because apparently some of the rows are not merged. Do you know why?

Comment: @user9660581  Do you need the duplicates as well?  In that case you have to either add that column as grouping column or create a string by concatenating the element or get a `list` output.  It is not clear though what you wanted

Comment: No, I don't need the duplicates. What I would like to achieve is to merge the rows by ID. Your solution perfectly works for the example above, however, for my actual dataset it does not, because some of the information is lost (i.e, in the case there are three duplicate IDs only two rows get merged but the third row gets deleted). Maybe there is another solution to your's?

Comment: @user9660581  Can you please update your post with a new example that reflect the issue and the expected output